# PermissionRequested Event not being raised in UWP

Tags: webview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app that has a WebView defined inside the MainPage.xaml file.

```
<WebView Name="webView" 
                 Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource WebViewStyle}}"
                 Visibility="{Binding WebAppLoading, Converter={StaticResource FalseToVisibleConverter}}"
                 local:WebViewExtensions.StartServiceRequest="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainPage.StartServiceRequest}"
                 local:WebViewExtensions.CommandExecutedByScript="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainPage.CommandExecutedByScript}" 
                 local:WebViewExtensions.NavigateBack="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainPage.NavigateBack}"
                 local:WebViewExtensions.InputPaneHeight="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainPage.InputPaneHeight}"
                 Loaded="OnWebViewLoaded"
                 ScriptNotify="OnScriptNotify" 
                 AllowFocusOnInteraction="False"
                 NavigationCompleted="OnNavigationCompleted"
                 NavigationStarting="OnNavigationStarting"
                 NewWindowRequested="OnNewWindowRequested"
                 PermissionRequested="OnPermissionRequested">
```

I have enabled Microphone capability in the UWP Manifest file. I see the Windows Pop up requesting consent to use Microphone. However, the OnPermissionRequested function is not being invoked. I have a breakpoint that is not kicking in. After I say yes to the Microphone consent, I dont see the functionality working.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this further? Determine if the WebViewControl.PermissionRequested Event is triggered in the first place?

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

The Windows pop-up is popped up for the app by the system,the system request and the WebView's PermissionRequested are two different things.So when you click the yes to the Microphone consent,the PermissionRequested doesn't be triggered.Only when you prepare to use a microphone in the webView (e.g. call) will trigger the method.If you want to know if the microphone's privacy settings are turned on,you can use the following code to judue.

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-microphone"));
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation... i don't see PermissionRequested getting triggered even when I try to use the Microphone...i will try to get the info on privacy setting and update...

Comment: When I try to use the call in webView, it does trigger. Can you provide the URL of the webView you visited?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a webView deep inside an imported SDK that I did not change.. As soon as i added the corresponding Even Delegate in that webView, it started to work as expected..